# How to display html file stored in local PC from chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to display a html file stored in local PC in another HTML. How do I do that? I tried using iframes and giving file:/// protocol. It gives me Not allowed to load local resource: error.

Answer (score 0):

In a Chrome App, to access local files / folders you need to use the [`chrome.fileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) and get the user to select the file/folder for you (works as access approval that you can retain for later).

You can't use `file:///` from a Chrome App.

Comment: I am pretty new to the chrome app development. I am not sure how to use chrome.filesystem API. Can you please help with some sample code? It would be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access) is a good starting point if you want sample code.